# Reverse Polarity Protection for GPIO header powered Raspberry Pi 4: Diode with 1, 2 or 5 A?

Tags: diodes, raspberry-pi, reverse-polarity

For my project I power a Raspberry Pi 4 over the GPIO header. I use a breadboard which looks like that:

[image]

In order to protect the Raspberry from reverse polarity I thought about a simple solution: I would solder a rectifier diode antiparallel between the +5 V and GND rail. That way, in normal mode the diode will not draw any current - but in case of reverse polarity it will behave like a short circuit and therefore draw so much current that the original Raspberry power supply ([datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/power-supply/usb-c-power-supply-product-brief.pdf)) would switch into a short-circuit state.

The downside of this is, that a diode with 4 or 5 A is significantly bigger than a diode for up to 2 A. Therefore, I thought about using a diode with only 2 A (or even 1 A), as it would still cause the power supply to switch into the short-circuit state. In that case, the diode would be relieved and therefore would not be required to resist the ~ 3,4 A the power supply will deliver before switching into short-circuit state.

But if the diode dies, that will be a problem because then the reverse polarity protection will not work any more.

My main questions are:

1. Is a rectifier diode with 1 A (1N4007, [datasheet](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/A400/1N400X_ENG_TDS.pdf)) or 2 A (1N5060, [datasheet](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/A400/HZ1N5059-1N5062_D_E.pdf)) safe? Will it resist until the power supply switches into short-circuit state? Or is it better to use a one with 4-5 A?
2. Is there a better solution which is as simple? There is not much space left on the breadboard.
3. Let's say the reverse polarity is not noticed and therefore the Raspberry power supply is left in short-circuit state for a few months. Will that be safe?

And a theoretical question:

4. In case the power supply would not switch into the short-circuit state, the voltage would drop always to about 0.00 V, even if its only for a few (milli)seconds until the diode dies, right?

**EDIT:** I did some tests using two LEDs:

- 1 A: The LED will glow for a very short time period.
- 2 A: The glow is much less.
- 5 A: Not different from 2 A.

In all cases, I can measure about –0,4 to –0,6 V but somehow the diode with 2 A seems to be superior to the one with 1 A. I think this reverse voltage is way too high.

Comment: The diode data sheet might show a graph showing maximum current or power depending on how long it lasts for. Max peak current can be a lot higher than max sustained current.

Comment: I edited my post. It seems that - anyway - the reverse voltage would be way too high :(

Comment: If you use a powerful Schottky diode like SK54C there, the remaining reverse voltage should be low enough to protect the Raspberry. The diode will become hot on the long run, the cathode should be soldered to a large metal area.

Comment: Thank you! Does the diode need the 5 A or could be 1 or 2 A also be enough (since the power supply will switch into short circuit-mode)?